# Hide overflowing items in a Panel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `VirtualizingStackPanel` with items from an `ItemsSource`. There are more items than space to display all the items in the `VirtualizingStackPanel`.

Example: I have space for 5.3 items but i have 7 items. Now i want the `VirtualizingStackPanel` to show 5 items and hide the rest.

Problem: The panel shows 6 items. The last item is overflowing.

Is it possible to show only 5 items (= no overflowing items) in this case, only with XAML?

The current code of my StackPanel:

```
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource rpTemplate}" ItemsSource="...">
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And my DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="rpTemplate">
  <Label Content="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
</DataTemplate>
```

It don't have to be `VirtualizingStackPanel`, it can be a StackPanel, DockPanel, whatever, as long as i can list the items.

Comment: You could declare a custom `Panel` to do that for you, but creating custom virtualizing `Panel`s is not for the feint hearted.

Comment: @Sheridan I can use a custom `Panel` too (updated my question). Can you explain a little bit more what steps are required to archieve that kind of panel?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is off topic for this website as it is far too broad and too complex. There is a good chapter that covers it in the WPF Control Development Unleashed book, but unfortunately their previously available online version is no longer available.

Comment: I recall answering something very similar a while back. Does this question help you? [Virtualizing Panel that doesn't crop items](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9416047/302677)

Comment: @Rachel: I currently working on my problem, your solution is helping me, thanks. I am working on a little bit different approach with an attached property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 3 solutions:

The first one (mentioned from Rachel in the comments) is [using a converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416047/virtualizing-panel-that-doesnt-crop-items?lq=1).

The second one (i found this is the easiest): [make a new class inherited from my Panel and use that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364127/wpf-metro-style-making-listview-show-only-complete-items)

And i tried a third solution and found a solution with [Blend behaviors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443470/change-children-of-stackpanel-when-stackpanel-parent-is-resizing)